# How to count rows in excel starting in specified cell with vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question regarding how to count cells in excel using vba, I've found this code but is not working as intended

```
Dim count As Long
count= ActiveSheet.Range("B5", ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlDown)).Rows.count
MsgBox count
```

My problem is, lets say my data header is in cell B4 and my data starts starts from B5 to an unknown row in the same B column. How could I count how many rows are filled (starting from B5) ?   (there are no blank cells)

I also have found how to assign the values from the range to the array as

```
 MyVector = Range("B5:B" & count).Value
```

But I don't know how to know the count variable

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**: for proper range to Array sizing

- data starts from B5
- there are no blank cells

then use this

```
Dim count As Long
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown)))

Dim MyVector As Variant
MyVector = Range("B5").Resize(count).Value
```

or, directly:

```
Dim MyVector As Variant
MyVector = Range("B5").Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown)))).Value
```

However, if there can be no data at all, then check count before filling the array:

```
Dim count As Long
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown)))

Dim MyVector As Variant
If count > 0 Then MyVector = Range("B5").Resize(count).Value
```

Comment: Be careful because if no data after B5 that will go to the end of the sheet.

Comment: @SJR, the OP said _"there are no blank cells"_ and in any case I also gave code for _"if there can be no data at all"_ scenario. So I've been careful

Answer (score 2):

Use column B (not 1="A") and work up from the bottom just in case you only have one entry (you are trying to go down from the very last row in the sheet).

```
Dim count As Long
count= ActiveSheet.Range("B5", ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count,"B").End(xlUp)).count
MsgBox count
MyVector = Range("B5").Resize(count).Value
```

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks, I think my edit using Resize will take care of that (of course one could dispense with the variable altogether).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
Dim count As Long
count= ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Row - 5 + 1
MsgBox count

MyVector = Range("B5:B" & count + 4).Value
```

Comment: Wait, if the OP wants to use `count` in `MyVector = Range("B5:B" & count).Value` then we want the actual row and not the count of the range or the ending will be 5 off.

Comment: @ScottCraner What about now?

Comment: Why do the math then undo the math?  Just remove the `-5+1` and the `+4`

Comment: ^ yup over thought this one, you have the beginning and the end to define the range.

Comment: @ScottCraner Because I thought that maybe the OP still wants to know the number of cells with values after `B5`, that is why he used `count`. If he wants to know the value, he can just call `count` whenever he wants.